# Rails 5: form_for select field tag with select class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to implement an select_tag, the problem I'm facing is that every css element works, except the select option. Somehow the bootstrap stylesheet gets called when I use `f.select :home_type, [["Room", "Room"]], class: 'add-listing__input'`

This stylesheet gets called and only select works

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/triptip-assets.min.self-3157b4719675b23587e706840e28dab5a7506a2794b67521ade419a505a34070.css?body=1
```

When I use for example `f.text_field` everything works and this stylesheet gets called

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/style.self-6fdbeaf8dfea504b6f923ccefbf5f6a7f370c6436cf98feefac201fc92c78f83.css?body=1
```

#### EDIT

Here is my form

```
  <%= form_for @room do |f| %>
    <div class="add-listing__form-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label class="add-listing__label">
            Home Type:
          </label>
          <%= f.select :home_type, [["Wohngebäude", "Wohngebäude"], ["Bürogebäude", "Bürogebäude"], ["Haus", "Haus"], ["Geschäft", "Geschäft"]], class: 'add-listing__input js-example-basic-multiple' %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label class="add-listing__label">
            Vacancy Type:
          </label>
          <%= f.select :vacancy_type, [["Leer", "Leer"], ["Voll", "Voll"]], class: 'add-listing__input js-example-basic-multiple' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label class="add-listing__label">
            Accomodate:
          </label>
          <%= f.number_field :accomodate, id: "amount", placeholder: "Für wie viele Personen?", class: "add-listing__input" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label class="add-listing__label">
            Abrissgerüchte:
          </label>
          <%= f.text_field :rumors, id: "rumors", placeholder: "Abrissgerüchte?", class: "add-listing__input" %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post your form ? Or just the select tag

Comment: I added the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define class in select field in this way:

```
<%= f.select(:vacancy_type, [ ... ], {}, { class: 'my_style_class' }) %>
```